# Does Mass Effect 3 have a secret ending?

Tags: mass-effect-3

There's a rumor that if you finish a second game of ME3 or import a ME2 save file you get an extra secret ending.  I've also heard that this is just:

> The epilogue with the child and the old man, or the Shepard lives ending if you pick destroy with greater than 4000.

Anyone know for sure?

Comment: I think the old man telling the kid the story at the end is Shepard :)

Comment: Just want to say, I played as FemShep, if it were true that the grandpa was Shep, it would've had to have been a girl in my playthrough. And as for it potentially being Shep's kid, it would've been impossible for a femshep... she would've had to have given birth to the kid before she died... I got the ending where shep appears for 10 and you see that she breathes... I haven't played through a second time yet. It is killing me to even think about another playthrough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any secret ending, there is only a "perfect" ending which gives you hope that Shepard survived, that's it. But as mentioned by Vasil, you need to destroy all synthetic life and get AT LEAST 4.000 Effective military strength and "save" Anderson by either having high enough paragon or renegade or by shooting the Illusive man. This is the only "secret" ending I know of.

Answer (score 2):

> I beat ME3 with the military strenth of over 5000 and i destroyed the reapers with an imported ME2 profile and all a got was hope that shepard lived and a little clip at he end with an old man talking to his kid about the story of shepared

Answer (score -1):

If you choose to destry the reapers there is a secret (rare) ending where it shows Sheaperd all burned up lying on the ground.And you can only see his dogtag!But for a second he gasps for air which is assumed the he has survived!

Comment: You can get that on a first play through with a high enough EMS.  This is supposed to be an additional post credit sequence.