# "Secret" ending in Mass effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Mass Effect 3 have a secret ending?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55071/does-mass-effect-3-have-a-secret-ending)

I know that many people are asking about the secret ending where

> Shepard is seen beneath a pile of rubble and taking a deep breath. I just finished the game with 5000+ War assets, and with an imported ME2 character but still didn't get this ending. I chose to destroy the Reapers, and the renegade option at the confrontation with The Illusive Man, hence the death of Anderson. Only some of my crew survived on the jungle planet, and the Stargazer thing. Any idea what I did wrong?

I think my War assets were at 5000+, but my Effective rating was around 3750. Could this be the reason?

Comment: Please learn how to use spoiler tags. I don't really care, but there are people who wouldn't have completed the game and might have opened your question. For future reference, it's a >! before the spoiler-y lines.

Comment: My mistake. I guess i owe an apology to the players that despite have not finished their game still enters a thread which reads "Secret ending". What's been seen for them cannot be unseen now, and i didn't force any onto this thread. You didn't answer my question.

Comment: No problem. I've already submitted an edit for the spoiler tags. The reason why I didn't answer your question was because I was waiting for ME3 to come out before starting the series. I just started with ME1.. :D

Comment: I guess I missed the sarcasm in your comment. Oops.

Comment: Yes you did. But thank you for fixing my post. :)

Comment: I see spoilers here everywhere that has not been censored, and my post have been edited by others than me two times now. Remove the thing instead?

Comment: @Sebbe having your post edited by others is part of the way the Stackexchange network works, and isn't any sort of implied criticism of you or your post.  Once you have enough rep, you'll be able to edit other people's posts, too.

Comment: @Sebbe Just a note... if spoilers aren't in a spoiler tag and they're near the top of the question, there's a risk that someone could see them on the question list on the front page. The spoiler tag hides them from the question summary on the front page. So it's still possible for people to accidentally see them without the spoiler tag, even if they never click on the question.

Answer (score 0):

The endings are keyed off of effective military strength. You would need to either gain additional war assets, or raise your readiness rating.

> By doing this you can get the "Shepard Lives" ending.  I think the effective rating has to be 4000 if Anderson gets shot once, and 5000 if Anderson is shot a second time by The Illusive Man.

Answer (score 0):

If you have over 5000 total military strength you will get the "best ending", regardless of any other factors. There are a number of other endings (6-8) I believe, that you can get for under 5000.

Source : http://www.gamersheroes.com/mass-effect-3-war-asset-guide